# Given integer n decide if it is possible to represent it as a sum of two squares of integers

Tags: c++, c

### INPUT SPECIFICATION:

> First line of input contains one integer `t <= 10000`: number of test cases.
>   T lines follow, each of them consisting of exactly one integer `0 <= n <= 10^8`.

### OUTPUT SPECIFICATION:

> For each test case output `Yes` if it is possible to represent given number as a sum of two squares and `No` if it is not possible.

Comment: Do you need an algorithm or do you have one that's too slow?

Comment: This isn't a place where you can drop of your assignment requirements and pick the solution later. If you're having trouble with a specific aspect of coding, feel free to ask.

Comment: Two things. 1) Is this C or C++? The difference is important. 2) Please post your attempt so far, and then we'll see if we can help with the specific parts you don't understand. You won't get much help if you don't have a place to start with!

Comment: You forgot about time and memory limit. This seems to be a classical ACM-like algorithmic problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: A number N is expressible as a sum of 2 squares **iff** in the prime factorization of N, every prime of the form (4k+3) occurs an even number of times!

Comment: +1. It would be good if you post the proof also. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz : [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) might be helpful.

Comment: this is my 1st ques in site...founded some codes but was for given integers or sum of integers .. not getting idea for this one so was looking for hint..i don need full algo..@prasoon thanks

Comment: @glowcoder .. code in c will help me :) :gman..its not a assighnment...a daily quiz question i use to solve..

Comment: Yes that is well known, the proof is rather huge. This is not a programming question though as such.