# How to check if a for a given number N, N^2 can be expressed as the sum of squares of two non-zero integers?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a number N, how can I find out if N^2 can be expressed as the sum of squares of two non-zero integers. For example if N=10, 10^2 can be expressed as (6^2)+(8^2). I've read that such numbers N can be expressed as 4k+1 but even 9 fits that expression, but 81 cant be expressed as the sum of squares of two integers. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Er, 81 = 9² + 0²… but 4k+1 is about the number itself, so an answer for 9 would be 3² + 0².

Comment: He needs greater then 0.

Comment: [How to determine whether a number can be written as a sum of two squares?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/787321/90333), [Number as sum of two squares](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4536), [Testing whether an integer is the sum of two squares](http://mathoverflow.net/q/57981/81296), [How do I find if a number can be represented as a sum of two squares?](http://qr.ae/RPJFhZ), [Represent natural number as sum of squares using dynamic programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3967769/995714)

Comment: A closed duplicate: [Given integer n decide if it is possible to represent it as a sum of two squares of integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5055527/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc not actually a duplicate, as it turns out that "is n^2 the sum of two squares" permits an optimization that "is n the sum of two squares" doesn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers you want are the hypotenuses ("c" values) of pythagorean triples, series [A009000](http://oeis.org/A009000) in OEIS. The comments there point out that a number is a hypotenuse if and only if it's divisible by at least one prime of the form 4k+1. So you can check whether a number is a hypotenuse by obtaining its prime factorization and then seeing whether any of those primes have a remainder of 1 when divided by 4.

In the case of your example, 81 doesn't qualify because its only prime factor is 3. 81 is divisible by 9, but 9 isn't prime.

Answer (score 1):

Use this object, "c" is your number If "a" and "b" not equal to null after your run checkPi() method a,b and c are Pythagorean triple.

```
<?php

Class PithgorasTriplesDetector {

    /**
     * 
     * @var type 
     */
    private $a, $b, $c;

    /**
     *
     * @var type 
     */
    private $check_numbers = array();

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $c
     */
    public function __construct($c) {
        $this->c = $c;
        $this->check_numbers = range(1, $this->c);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function checkPi() {
        $counter = count($this->check_numbers);
        $c_pow = pow(2, $this->c);
        for ($index = $counter - 1; $index >= 0; $index--) {
            for ($index2 = $index; $index2 > 0; $index2--) {
                if ($this->calcAB($index, $index2) == $c_pow) {
                    $this->a = $index;
                    $this->b = $index2;
                    return true;
                }
                if ($this->calcAB($index, $index2) > $c_pow) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $a
     * @param type $b
     * @return type
     */
    public function calcAB($a, $b) {
        return pow(2, $a) + pow(2, $b);
    }

    function getA() {
        return $this->a;
    }

    function getB() {
        return $this->b;
    }

    function getC() {
        return $this->c;
    }

    function setA($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function setB($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    function setC($c) {
        $this->c = $c;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Pythagoras Calculator.

This link can helps you, all PYTHAGOREAN TRIPLES

http://www.tsm-resources.com/alists/trip.html

Comment: I've gone through that already but it isnt working as N may be as large as 10^6